# How to check that dvd-rw is erased?

Tags: shell, ubuntu, dd, dvd, data-cd

I formatted dvd-rw disc with the following command

```
dvd+rw-format -blank=full /dev/sr0
```

If I try the command `dd if=/dev/sr0 bs=2048 | hexdump -C`, nothing happens.

How to verify that every bit of the disc has been erased?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `dvd+rw-mediainfo` command to see if your DVD is totally blank:

If the DVD is blank:

```
dvd+rw-mediainfo /dev/sr0 | grep status
Disc status:           blank
```

If not:

```
dvd+rw-mediainfo /dev/sr0 | grep status
Disc status:           complete
```